# Stacked divs with offsets relative to sibling divs

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I have a div that streatches the full height of the screen. I want to put three divs in there: header, content, and footer, with the header sticking to the top and footer to the bottom and content fitting in between. The solutions I've found to do this requires me to define a height for the footer and/or header, and then giving the center div a margin equal to the that height, which I want to leave undefined (they should stretch to fit their content). Is there a way to do this without using javascript?

When browser resizes, the footer and header should stay the same, and the center should shrink.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.stretchedToMargin {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="stretchedToMargin">

    <div>
        Header (style="top:0") Indefinite height. 
        expands to fit content without scrolling.
    </div>

    <div>
        Content
        Fits between header and footer, using the pixels leftover 
        scrolling if needed
    </div>

    <div>Footer (style="bottom:0") Indefinite height.
        expands to fit content without scrolling.
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Using a table (since it appears this is not possible with CSS only)  as follows also doesn't work. The long text spills out of the whole layout, no scrollbars appear...

```
<div class="stretchedToMargin">

    <table style="height:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="height:1px;">Header</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div style="height:100%; overflow:auto;">...Long text...</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height:100px">Footer</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: What browsers you need to support?

Comment: what happens if i resize the browser? do they all shrink? or stay in size?

Comment: @bazmegakapa all of course! (IE 6+)

Comment: CSS only, i think it's not possible. you have to start off with at least setting an explicit height on some of them (like the header and footer)

Comment: @Joseph what if I set a px height for the footer, how do I do it then?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use `display:table` on the wrapper and `display:table-row` on the section divs however as usual the lame duck IE 7 doesn't support it so just use an actual `<table>`. Yes, it's not *semantic* but thats a small trade-off really.

Comment: I think this may be the only way but this is also giving me a problem in IE.
I tried the stretchedToMargin class on the table but that didn't work so I gave the table 100% height, that worked.
Then I created 3 rows with the last row having a height of 100px.
Then I put a div with 100% height with overflow:auto; inside the middle row and that worked works in chrome but in IE 8 the div doesn't overflow.
Can you please help with a table solution to this?

Comment: Firstly, you haven't closed your `div`. Secondly, relative dimensions and overflow don't always work as you'd expect with child elements of table cells (the correct behaviour is actually undefined in the CSS standard) so just remove the div entirely since it doesn't appear to serve any real purpose.

Comment: Sorry, nevermind. I just realised you want the center to scroll. Your problem is that the height of a cell is defined by the height of its contents but you're asking the contents to be defined by the height of the cell. That's a chicken-and-egg contradiction that the standard doesn't attempt to solve.

Comment: ... Having said that you might want to try an extra nested div inside the 100% high parent and try an overflow on that.

Comment: that also doesn't work. It looks like when I do 100% height, the browser interprets it as 100% of the table, instead of the cell. sigh

Comment: An element with percentage height takes its height from the closest ancestor with a relative or absolute position and a defined height. If a parent has a percentage height then its parent must also right up to the top of the DOM. Trouble is you can't position table cells and they don't follow the normal rules regarding height. You'll also find alternatives like `top:0;bottom:0` don't work as expected. Your requirements have strayed outside the spec and it's up to browser vendors what happens.

Comment: oh well, back to the drawing board i guess. :-/ thanks for your inputs